# How can I include a percent sign in QUrl

Tags: c++, qurl

I'm new in c++ from this afternoon and I am having a hard time.

I have the below line:

```
const QUrl command("http://192.168.11.11/subdomain/letters?t=somekeyword&p=%01")
```

But when the QUrl "command" is sent used in QNetworkAccessManager, it is actually being sent adding **25** after the % sign.
Now I understand that QUrl is in TolerantMode, and is adding it thinking it's a user input error.

Unwanted result:

```
http://192.168.11.11/subdomain/letters?t=somekeyword&p=%2501
```

How would I prevent my url to be modified?

I tried to double my percent sign and inserting a backslash as well.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What version of QT are we talking about here?

Comment: Also, are you trying to URL encode the non printable character "SOH, start of heading" in the URL above? Otherwise %01 does not make any sense.

Comment: I'm using QT in the blackberry SDK, and for what I understand it is QT4
Also, this is a command sent to a webserver, %01 is power on, %00 is power off

Comment: Qt 4.8.4 to be precise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be a tricky problem. Here is the solution I came up with:

**Code**

```
QByteArray rawQuery("t=somekeyword&p=%01");
QUrl command("http://192.168.11.11/subdomain/letters");
command.setEncodedQuery(rawQuery);
std::cout << command.toEncoded().data();
```

**Result**

`http://192.168.11.11/subdomain/letters?t=somekeyword&p=%01`

**Notes**

The solution relies on some behavior described in setEncodedQuery, which states

> Sets the query string of the URL to query. The string is inserted as-is, and no further encoding is performed when calling toEncoded().
>
> This function is useful if you need to pass a query string that does not fit into the key-value pattern, or that uses a different scheme for encoding special characters than what is suggested by QUrl.
>
> Passing a value of QByteArray() to query (a null QByteArray) unsets the query completely. However, passing a value of QByteArray("") will set the query to an empty value, as if the original URL had a lone "?".

**References**

- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qurl.html#setEncodedQuery

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks for this well explained answer!